# Parse custom string to array Javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm

So I'm trying to parse specific sequence of string in JavaScript. Basically i need to parse `(123 abc)(())` where () is like openning array and closing, and values in the array would be split by spaces.
For example:
`(133 abs)(())` will give me `[["123", "abs"],[[]]]`
No JQuery or ragex,only vanilla JavaScript

i tried doing but it errors with recursion error, can't really send the try due it was on another computer

Comment: Please provide the code you tried and got you the mentioned error.

Comment: Problem statement is unclear. Also, What did you tried so far ? Can you please help with some code so that can we can look into that and help you.

Comment: @RohìtJíndal i can't do it, like i stated the code was on another pc

Comment: Is `(1 '2' ())` valid?

Comment: @Cherry Ten try again, and explain what you did. You should not expect anyone here to invest more time helping you than you did writing the question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this do what you need? No RegExp. No JQuery.

This splits the input string into codepoints and recursively enumerates that array.

The base recursive step is to check if we have reached the end of the codepoint array, at which point we exit the recursion.

For each codepoint we use a switch statement to choose the value to insert into the result depending on the current codepoint, the previous codepoint, and whether we are inside an "item".

Codepoint by codepoint a result string is constructed. This code will probably break for Unicode strings containing grapheme clusters.

```js
const transform = (str) => {
    let result = []
    let withinItem = false
    const arr = [...str] // split into codepoints

    const next = (arr, pos, prev = null) => {
      if(pos >= arr.length) return
      
      let curr = arr[pos]
      
      switch(true) {
        case curr === '(':
          prev === ')' && result.push(',')
          result.push('[')
          break
        case curr === ' ':
          result.push('", ')
          withinItem = false
          break
        case curr === ')':
          withinItem && result.push('"')
          result.push(']')
          withinItem = false
          break
        default:
          !withinItem && result.push('"')
          result.push(curr)
          withinItem = true
          break
      }
      next(arr, ++pos, curr)
    }
    next(arr, 0)
    return `[${result.join('')}]`
}

console.log(transform('(133 abs)(())'))
```